# Restructuring Existing HTML Files

Tags: html, regex, vi

There has been times where I need to "convert" an old HTML structure to a new one. To illustrate, converting this:

```
<!-- Old HTML structure. -->
<div class="class-a">
  <div class="class-b">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
  <div class="class-c">
    <p>How are you doing?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class-a">
  <div class="class-b">    
  ... (and so on, basically repeats the construct above) ...
```

To something like:

```
<!-- New HTML structure. -->
<div class="class-aa">
  <span class="class-ab">Hello</span>
  <p>How are you doing?</p>
</div>
<div class="class-aa">
  <span class="class-ab">Hi!</span>
  ... (and so on, basically repeats the construct above) ...
```

Note that I still need the text, but the structure needs a complete overhaul.

The worst situation is the HTML file is super long and doing it manually (yep, a lot of typing). What I've been doing so far is either using a simple substitution regex (if not too complex) or resorting to the old school [vi macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros).

Would somebody please suggest a better approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you _define_ the changes you want to make _exactly_? (If not, how do you expect to "explain" them to any tool that would carry them out? If yes, let's hear the details so we'll be able to help you better.)

Comment: @Tom: The simple example above is representative of what I was trying to do. Please look at the comment by RoToRa below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a JavaScript/jQuery that does the restructuring and then use the DOM inspector/debugger of the browser get a copy of the modified HTML.

BTW, a while ago I was looking for a editor/tool that does this kind of thing automatically, but there doesn't seem to be such a thing: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79615/html-text-editor-with-dom-manipulation

Comment: That's quite clever, you could also manipulate the dom using php or python (and some others) with their built-in libraries. If you have more files, I think that would be easier to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to manipulate the structure (you seem sympathetic to a "DOM") of the HTML, rather than the text.  And you want to do this because by normalizing the HTML into a DOM-like structure, you get rid of the issues of text layout, HTML tags spelled in funny case, presence/absence of attributes, etc.

Probabaly not as convenient as you'd like, but a [source-to-source program transformation system](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) might do the trick.

Such a tool parses the text of a language (in your case, HTML) and builds an AST, a data structure
somewhat like a DOM in that it captures the exact structure of the code, e.g., tags, thier nesting, and attached attributes and text.  Once you have posession of the AST,  you can apply transformations to the AST using the HTML surface syntax you know and love(?).  The transformations
operate on the structure, not text, so you don't get the troubles you have with text.
After tansformation, you regenerate the language (HTML) text from the revised AST.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is one of these kinds of tools.  You could write the change you desired above as a transformation:

```
domain HTML;

rule revise_div(t1: text, t2:text):div_tag->div_tag =
"<div class="class-a"> 
   <div class="class-b"> 
     <span>\t1</span> 
   </div> 
  <div class="class-c"> 
     <p>\t2</p> 
  </div> 
</div>"
    ->
"<div class="class-aa">   
    <span class="class-ab">\t1</span>   
      <p>\t2</p>   
 </div>";
```

This rewrite rule has three parts: a header, containing the rule name, and parameter declarations which indicate what kinds of placeholders will be bound in the body of the rule, a left-hand-side match pattern (inside the quote marks), and right hand side replacement pattern (following the ->) also inside quotes.  The quotes are not HTML quotes; the are rule rewrite syntax "metaquotes" that separate the HTML syntax from that the transformation rule syntax.

The parameters in this case are intended to represent the two text strings t1 and t1; they are found insdie the patterns as \t1 and \t2, with the \ being a rewrite rule metaescape since these parameter names are not part of html, but simply represent the text found there.

The rewrite engine, given this rule, will match a point in the AST (or all points, depending on how you invoke it), bind t1 and t2 to the matching strings, remove the matched subtree (HTML in the match pattern), and replace it by the right hand side pattern with the t1 and t2 matched values substituted.

If your HTML is *really* regular in its usage, this will be very convenient. You can code these rules and apply repeatedly to many files. You'll be able to write a number rules that cover the variations.    I'd worry a bit that much HTML is written by random programmer of the moment and they aren't consistent about what they do, and no fixed set of rules will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... couldn't you just do the substitution?

```
<div class="class-a">
  <div class="class-b">
    <span>
```

becomes

```
<div class="class-aa">
  <span class="class-ab">
```

and

```
</span>
  </div>
  <div class="class-c">
    <p>
```

becomes

```
</span>
  <p>
```

lastly,

```
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

turns into

```
</p>
</div>
```

If you're document is indeed exactly the same structure over and over, you should be able to do it with these three find + replace commands. Simpler than writing a script or figuring out a regex.

Comment: This is definitely doable when the structure isn't too complex; the snippets above is for illustration only. In practice, the target HTML file might not have that exact spacing, capitalization, etc. to always conform the search-and-replace criteria.

Comment: Right, then you're bound to a more complex solution... Is the structure of the text always the same? Ie. is it always caption-header-comment or something like that? In that case you could strip the tags, put the real content in an array and fill your new html code while looping over the array.